# Наложение полупрозрачного фона на тело документа с изображением

Tags: css, background

Вообщем ситуация такая. Есть тело документа в котором имеется изображение, на которое требуется наложить полупрозрачный фон, не используя при этом блоки.
Возможно ли в данном случае это реализовать? Если да - то как?

```
body {
font-family: 'ubuntu';
margin: 0;
background: url(/images/back-1.jpg);
Background-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.5);
background-size: cover;}
```

Answer (score 2):

ТО что тебе надо, это свойство в css называется  background-blend-mode. Более подробно найдешь [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode)

```css
#div1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: url('https://get.wallhere.com/photo/temple-sunset-city-cityscape-reflection-sky-skyline-skyscraper-evening-morning-tower-France-Paris-Eiffel-Tower-dusk-spire-tree-landmark-186143.jpg'), red;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```